# Difference between $\mathrm{rot}$ and $\mathrm{Rot}$ (Curl)

Tags: rotations, vector-fields

I'm not sure whether you've heard of that difference at all and if it's of importance in English notations. In German at least you define:

$$\mathrm{rot\,\textbf{V}} = \nabla \times \textbf{V}, \quad\text{where $\textbf{V}$ is a continuously differentiable Vectorfield $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$} $$

and at the same way

$$\mathrm{Rot}\textbf{V} = \frac{1}{2}\,\left(\textbf{V'-V'$^T$}\right),\quad \text{where $\textbf{V'}$ should equal $\mathrm{Jacobian(\textbf{V})}$}$$

I'm just aware of: $\mathrm{rot}$ describes a vector, $\mathrm{Rot}$ a matrix.  What's the matter?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What's the difference, especially if they almost sound the same but aren't? Did you hear about them?

Comment: I've never seen the usage of $\mathrm{Rot}$ (at least in italian, english and french context), but the symmetric part of the Jacobian appears frequently in fluid mechanics and elasticity, so maybe it's a notation that is more common in those fields. Did you encounter it in these subjects? I still don't quite understand what's your question though. It is just a notation, what is to be understood?

Comment: Are they the same? Respectively how can u get from one to another. There must be a link, they must have something in common. Don't they?

Comment: They are not the same of course. The components of $\mathrm{rot}$ appear as off-diagonal entries of $\mathrm{Rot}$, rescaled by a factor $1/2$. Just write the expressions for the components to verify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Neg}{\phantom{-}}\DeclareMathOperator{\Rot}{Rot}\DeclareMathOperator{\rot}{rot}$There's a vector space isomorphism between $\Reals^{3}$ and the set of skew-symmetric real $3 \times 3$ matrices given by
$$
\phi\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}} a_{1} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{3} \\ \end{array}\right]
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    \Neg0 & -a_{3} & \Neg a_{2} \\
    \Neg a_{3} & \Neg0 & -a_{1} \\
    -a_{2} & \Neg a_{1} & \Neg 0 \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$
Under this isomorphism, the cross product corresponds to matrix multiplication in the sense that
$$
\Vec{a} \times \Vec{v} = \phi(\Vec{a})\Vec{v}
\quad\text{for all $\Vec{v}$ in $\Reals^{3}$.}
$$
It turns out that $\phi(\rot\Vec{V}) = \Rot \Vec{V}$.

---

To establish this claim, let $\Vec{V}$ be a continuously-differentiable vector field and expand to first order at an arbitrary point:
$$
\Vec{V}(\Vec{x}) = \Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0}) + D\Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0})(\Vec{x} - \Vec{x}_{0}) + o(\|\Vec{x} - \Vec{x}_{0}\|).
$$
If we write the Jacobian
$$
D\Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0})
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
    a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1} \\
    a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2} \\
    a_{3} & b_{3} & c_{3} \\
  \end{array}\right],
$$
then by definition
\begin{align*}
  \Rot\Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0})
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}\bigl[D\Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0}) - D\Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0})^{\mathsf{T}}\bigr] \\
  &= \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
      0 & b_{1} - a_{2} & c_{1} - a_{3} \\
      a_{2} - b_{1} & 0 & c_{2} - b_{3} \\
      a_{3} - c_{1} & b_{3} - c_{2} & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
A short calculation gives
$$
\rot \Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0}) = (\nabla \times \Vec{V})(\Vec{x}_{0})
= \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    b_{3} - c_{2} \\
    c_{1} - a_{3} \\
    a_{2} - b_{1} \\
  \end{array}\right],
$$
so we have $\phi(\rot \Vec{V})(\Vec{x}_{0}) = \Rot \Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0})$.

This, incidentally, is how the curl quantifies rotation in the flow of $\Vec{V}$. If we decompose $A := D\Vec{V}(\Vec{x}_{0})$ as a sum of a skew-symmetric matrix $R$, a traceless symmetric matrix $S_{0}$, and a scalar matrix $T$ (multiple of the identity), then to first order in $t$, $\exp(tA) = \exp(tR) \exp(tS_{0}) \exp(tT)$. The respective factors on the right are a rotation (the curl), a volume-preserving deformation, and a scaling (the divergence).

Comment: Thank you, makes the association pretty clear

Comment: You're very welcome (and I learned of the Rot operator)!

Comment: This is a great explanation! I want to add that in German literature on electrodynamics, Rot (and also Div) are more specific. Given two vector fields $\vec{F_1}$ and $\vec{F_2}$ in two regions $R_1$ and $R_2$, respectively. If the two regions share a boundary surface, then Rot$(\vec{F}) := \vec{n_{12}} \times (\vec{F_2} - \vec{F_1})$ and Div$(\vec{F}) := \vec{n_{12}} \cdot (\vec{F_2} - \vec{F_1})$, where $\vec{n_{12}}$ is the normal vector at the interface, pointing from $R_1$ to $R_2$. In effect, Rot and Div describes how the fields behave at the interface between two regions.